# HTTP Error 500.19 while hosting Wcf Service

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I am hosting Wcf application on my local machine(32 bit machine).I am getting below error.

```
Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Attaching the Config file details for the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceDemo.ServiceCalculateCost" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceDemo.IServiceCalculateCost"></endpoint> 

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 implements "Configuration Locking". This is to help with IIS administration.

Here, look at the error details and how to resolve the same: [IIS 7 – This configuration section cannot be used at this path.](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2007/03/26/iis-7-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path/)

As per it, one of the resolution:

1. Open the `applicationHost.config` file, located here: `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`
2. Edit the "`handlers`" section.
3. Change this line:

   `<section name=”handlers” overrideModeDefault=”Deny” />`

   To:

   `<section name=”handlers” overrideModeDefault=”Allow” />`